# conway text, rectifiable curve

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question about this, I want to show

If $ f: G \to \mathbb{C} $ is analytic and $\gamma: [a,b] \to G$ is a continuous rectifiable curve in $G$, then $ f \circ\gamma $ is also a rectifiable curve.

So to show it is rectifiable, we need to show that $ f \circ \gamma$ is of bounded variation.

Note: The def of bounded variation as used in Conway is 
[image]

I thought since $f$ is continuous, then $f \circ \gamma$ is a continuous function and $ [a,b]$  is a compact set, so $ f \circ \gamma$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.  I thought I might be able to use this to show that it is of bounded variation but I got kinda stuck.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just using the fact that $f$ is (uniformly) continuous won't be enough; there are lots of uniformly continuous functions with unbounded variation.  You really do need the fact that $f$ is analytic.  Hint: try the mean value theorem.

Comment: The "variation" is the integral of "speed",(absolute value of velocity) so...

Comment: @NateEldredge thank you for your response, but I thought that MVT doesn't work for complex functions ??

Comment: It's a different statement than for real functions, but there is an analogous theorem; you get an inequality instead of an equality.

Comment: @NateEldredge Do you mind giving me the name of the theorem or a link to that? Cause I didn't learn about it yet.  thank you

Comment: I don't think it has a name other than "mean value theorem" or "mean value inequality".  One version might say the following: suppose $f$ is analytic on an open set $G$ which contains two points $z_0,z_1$ as well as the line segment $L$ joining them.  Suppose $|f'(z)| \le M$ for every $z \in L$.  Then $|f(z_1) - f(z_0)| \le M |z_1 - z_0|$.

Comment: @NateEldredge thank you for your help, I will check it out .